# Integration on a submanifold - Where is my mistake

Tags: integration, proof-verification, manifolds

Let $$M=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 \mid z=1-x^2-y^2, z>0\}$$ be a two-dimensional submanifold.

Now I need to integrate $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+x^2+y^2}$$ on $M$.

I have chosen $$\phi(\alpha,\beta):=(\cos\alpha\cos\beta,\sin\alpha\cos\beta,\sin^2\beta)$$ as a parametrization of $M$. Calculating the Gramian determinant I obtained $$\det((\phi'(\alpha,\beta))^T \phi'(\alpha,\beta))=(\sin^2\beta+4\cos^2\beta\sin^2\beta)(1+\cos^2\beta).$$
Applying it to $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\phi(\alpha,\beta))\sqrt{\det((\phi'(\alpha,\beta))^T \phi'(\alpha,\beta))}\,d\beta\,d\alpha$$ I get weird  results, so I'm wondering if I made a mistake until this point? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gramian determinant is incorrect. To retain your definition of volume element $\phi'$ must be defined as the transpose of Jacobian or else the volume element should be $\sqrt{\det(\phi'\phi'^\top)}$.
$$
\phi'=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin\alpha\cos\beta&-\cos\alpha\sin\beta\\
\cos\alpha\cos\beta&-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
0&\sin2\beta
\end{bmatrix}\\
\phi'^{\top}\phi'=\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin\alpha\cos\beta&\cos\alpha\cos\beta&0\\
-\cos\alpha\sin\beta&-\sin\alpha\sin\beta&\sin2\beta
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sin\alpha\cos\beta&-\cos\alpha\sin\beta\\
\cos\alpha\cos\beta&-\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
0&\sin2\beta
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos^2\beta&0\\
0&\sin^2\beta+\sin^22\beta
\end{bmatrix}\\
\sqrt{\det(\phi'^\top\phi')}=\sin\beta\cos\beta\sqrt{1+4\cos^2\beta}\\
f(x,y,z)={1\over2}\sqrt{1+4\cos^2\beta}
$$
So the required integral is
$$\begin{align}
&{1\over2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\sin\beta\cos\beta(1+4\cos^2\beta)d\beta d\alpha\\
=&\pi\int_0^{\pi\over2}\sin\beta\cos\beta(1+4\cos^2\beta)d\beta\\
=&\pi\int_0^{1}(t+4t^3)dt\quad[\;t=\cos\beta\;]\\
=&{3\pi\over2}
\end{align}
$$

> Another way

You could've chosen the Cartesian parametrization of your surface which looks like
$$
\phi(x,y)=(x,y,1-x^2-y^2),\quad x^2+y^2<1
$$
In this case the square-root of Gramian determinant turns out to be $\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2}$ and therefore our integral becomes
$$
{1\over2}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}(1+4x^2+4y^2)dxdy\\
={1\over2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1(1+4r^2)rdrd\theta\\
={3\pi\over2}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, always miscalculating with those matrices..

Comment: The latter solution even seems more elegant, thanks for that also